# DB2 SELECT COUNT, if NULL then default to 0

Tags: database, count, db2

**GOAL**

I am trying to select a user ID from one table and a count of associated items from another table in DB2.  I am trying to execute this query in SSIS to import the data into a SQL Server database where I will perform additional transformation processes on the data.  I mention the SSIS not because I think its part of the issue, but just for background info.  I'm fairly certain the problem lies with my inexperience in DB2.  My background is in SQL Server, I'm very new to DB2.

**ISSUE**

The problem occurs when (I'm assuming) the count is 0.  When I execute the query in my DB2 command editor, it just returns a blank row.  I would expect it to at least return the user ID and then just have a blank field for the count, but instead the whole row is blank.  This then causes issues with my SSIS package where its trying to do a bunch of inserts with no data.

Again, a lot of this is an assumption because I'm not experienced with DB2 Command Editor, or DB2, but if I open up the dates a bit, I will get the expected results (user id and count).

I've tried wrapping the count in a COALESCE() function, but that didn't resolve the issue.

**QUERY**

```
SELECT a.user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT b.item_number) as Count
FROM TABLE_A a
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_B b
ON a.PRIMARY_KEY = b.PRIMARY_KEY
WHERE a.user_id = '1234'
AND b.DATE_1 >= '01/01/2013'
AND b.DATE_1 <= '01/05/2013'
AND b.DATE_2 >= '01/01/2013'
AND b.DATE_2 <= '12/23/2014'
AND a.OTHER_FILTER_FIELD = 'ABC'
GROUP BY a.user_id
```

Comment: Your outer join is effectively an inner join, because you apply predicates against TABLE_B _after_ the join, so non-matching rows are eliminated. Put the date-related predicates _into_ the join condition.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the field in COALESCE()

```
 COUNT(DISTINCT COALESCE(b.item_number,0))
```

also make sure

```
 WHERE a.user_id = '1234'
```

exists in TABLE_A. If there is no user 1234 you will get no results with the query as written.

Comment: I have verified the user exists.  If I spread the dates out so they're like, a year apart, I will get the expected results, but it the dates are narrow, where the expected count might be 0, I get just a blank white row in DB2 command editor.  It happens when I add the COALESCE() function as well.  I'd upload a screen shot of the results window, but I don't have enough rep.  the results window looks weird because there's no borders on the columns like you would normally expect, its just a blank white row.

Comment: I see what its doing.  It looks weird because there are no rows returning.  If I do a query that actually gets a result, it shows a normal looking record with borders, and then the same white row underneath that, so that makes sense.  I'm just not getting any results at all which is weird.  I would expect to at least get the user_id

Comment: I think you need to look at your where clause.  It sounds like you have a typo there.  Since I don't know what you are trying to do I can't say but it seems to me if changing the dates gives you results then maybe the business rules are wrong on your where clause.

Comment: I've one by one added each condition to the where clause, and as long as items exist, I get a count.  As soon as the date span is narrow enough to where no items exist, I get no result, so I don't think its the where clause.

Comment: OK, let me see if I understand -- you want `COUNT()` to return 0?

Comment: I want a count of items, but if there are no items, I still need the the user_id and a 0, so that I can go and insert the user_id and a 0 into a table on another database.  As it stands, I get no results at all, when the desired result when there are no items would be '1234', '0'.

Comment: I guess worst case scenario I could figure out which ones didn't get a result after I do my database inserts and compare it against the other table I have with user_id's in it, but it seems like a pretty simple thing to have it just return 0.

Comment: you are sure you are doing a left join?  take out the group by and see if you have the expected results.